# Laravel not updating null values to foreign key column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a problem with laravel when I try to update the record and add it's foreign key to `NULL`

It didn't update at all.

There is no error and I check the `Mass Assignment` too.

Migration file:

```php
Schema::create('time_slots', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->id();
   $table->enum('duration', ['30', '60']);
   $table->double('price', 6, 2)->nullable();;
   $table->enum('currency', ['usd', 'egp'])->nullable();
   $table->dateTime('start_time');
   $table->dateTime('end_time');
   $table->enum('status', ['available', 'booked', 'finished'])->default('available');
   $table->enum('type', ['video', 'text', 'phone', 'not-set'])->default('not-set');
   $table->unsignedBigInteger('session_id');
   $table->foreign('session_id')->references('id')->on('sessions')->onDelete('cascade');
   $table->unsignedBigInteger('patient_id')->nullable();
   $table->foreign('patient_id')->references('id')->on('patients')->onDelete('cascade');
   $table->timestamps();
});
```

Update query

```php
$timeslot->currency = null;
$timeslot->price = null;
$timeslot->patient_id = null;
$timeslot->status = 'available'; // that is the only column that update correctly
$timeslot->save();
```

Comment: Tested with Laravel 7.16.1 and it runs without any errors and the data changes made to update an existing `Timeslot` record also get persisted. I have set `protected $guarded = [];` on `Timeslot` model.  MySQL  Ver 8.0.19, PHP 7.4.12. Are you getting any errors - maybe in log file(s)? Pls check

Comment: it fixes but really i don't know what happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace currency definition like this

```
$table->enum('currency', [null,'usd', 'egp'])->nullable();
```

or this

```
$table->enum('currency', ['usd', 'egp', null])->nullable()->default(null)
```

Comment: and what about the foreign key it's the most important one here

Comment: yeah im also looking it

Comment: Mine works perfectly.. Which laravel version are you trying

Comment: i use version 7